# Reuse InputStream and be compliant with Sonar rules

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have below method, which validates some xml content. The xml content is valid when in stards with element with local name that I have in `rootNameToUnmarshallerClassMap` map. It also must be valid against XSD file. So both validations are made in this method. There can be content that is XSD compliat but localName of start element is not in my `rootNameToUnmarshallerClassMap` map, this means that it is not valid from business point of view.

Below implementation has two problems: first is that I load big message to memory twice (`ByteArrayInputStream`) and second is that Sonar tells me to change try to try-with-resources as he see autoclosable `ByteArrayInputStream` usage.

Now question to more experienced developers - how can I fix it ? Thanks in advance.

```
 public void validate(InputStream content) throws ValidationException {
        XMLStreamReader streamReader = null;
        try {
            byte[] content = createByteArray(content);
            XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = getXmlInputFactory();
            streamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));
            navigateToFirstStartElement(streamReader);
            String localPart = streamReader.getName().getLocalPart();
            Class<? extends MyClass> jaxbClass = Optional.ofNullable(rootNameToUnmarshallerClassMap.get(localPart))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new ValidationException(String.format("Could not validate provided content, root element %s ", localPart)));
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(jaxbClass);
            SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = sf.newSchema(this.getClass().getResource("my.xsd"));
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
            ContentValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler = new ContentValidationEventHandler();
            unmarshaller.setEventHandler(validationEventHandler);
            unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));
            streamReader.close();
            if (validationEventHandler.getEvents().size() > 0) {
                throw new ValidationException(String.format("contnt was not xsd compliant"));
            }
        } catch (XMLStreamException | JAXBException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Could not validate provided content"));
        } finally {
            try {
                if (streamReader != null) {
                    streamReader.close();
                }
            } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it an option to use `BufferedInputStream` in combination with `mark` and `reset`? That could replace the `byte[]` and two `ByteArrayInputStream`s. The trickiest part is to determine the buffer size and mark limit. That would probably still give the try-with-resources warning, but I wouldn't listen to that. The `InputStream` that would be closed is the input to the method, and therefore not owned by your method.

Comment: yep the validate method is mine, so as an entry argument I should use BufferedInputStream ? Ok I will try, meanwhile I am waiting for other hints. Thanks.

Comment: I was more thinking wrapping the given input stream in a `BufferedInputStream` inside the method. That gives you all the flexibility you need for the buffer size and mark limit. Just not close it here (even if Sonar says you should); the caller should close the input stream it passed to this method.

Comment: Ok `BufferedInputStream` works with mark(0) and reset but sonar indeed reports error as I am not using try with resources. But caller uses try-with-resources so its fine.